# How do I get a constructor value to other methods to be modified?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The goal of this project is to refactor a previous solution to work with actual objects. Currently when I run the Jasmine tests I get these two errors:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined

Why is the class not recognizing the title value when I attempt to pass it into other methods? Prior to me trying to send the value into other methods it seemed to work but now that I am trying to send the string value to the titleCreator method it keeps on returning undefined.

```
class bookTitle {
    constructor(title) {
        this.title = this.titleCreator(title); // this sets a title value to the bookTitle object/class
    }

    titleCreator(string) {
        // Note that this isn't meant to be a fully fledged title creator, just designed to pass these specific tests
        var littleWords = ["and", "over", "the"]; // These are the words that we don't want to capitalize

        var modifiedString = this.string
        .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
        .map(function(word,index) {
            if (index == 0) {
                return capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
                return capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
            } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
            }
        })
        .join(' '); // Joins every element of an array into a string with a space inbetween each value. Basically you created a sentence from an array of words

        return modifiedString;

    }

    capitalize(word) {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
        // This function just capitalizes the word given to it
    }
}

module.exports = {
    bookTitle
}
```

Edit: Here are my Jasmine test cases for context. Idea of the program is just to pass these cases

```
var bookTitles = require ('./bookTitles.js');

describe('bookTitle', function() {

    var book; // this is the object that will be passed into the test cases, returns undefined here without beforeEach

    beforeEach(function() {
        book = new bookTitles.bookTitle(); // creates a new book instance before each test is run
    });

    describe('title', function() {
        it('should capitalize the first letter', function() {
            book.title = 'inferno';
            expect(book.title).toEqual('Inferno'); // works without capitalizing
        });

        it('should capitalize every word', function() {
            book.title = 'stuart little';
            expect(book.title).toEqual('Stuart Little');
        });

        describe('should capitalize every word except...', function() {
            describe('articles', function() {
                it('does not capitalize "the"', function() {
                    book.title = 'alexander the great';
                    expect(book.title).toEqual('Alexander the Great');
                });

                it('does not capitalize "a"', function() {
                    book.title = 'to kill a mockingbird';
                    expect(book.title).toEqual('To Kill a Mockingbird');
                });

                it('does not capitalize "an"', function() {
                    book.title = 'to eat an apple a day';
                    expect(book.title).toEqual('To Eat an Apple a Day');
                });
            });

            it('conjunctions', function() {
                book.title = 'war and peace';
                expect(book.title).toEqual('War and Peace');
            });

            it('prepositions', function() {
                book.title = 'love in the time of cholera';
                expect(book.title).toEqual('Love in the Time of Cholera');
            });
        });

        describe('should always capitalize...', function() {
            it('I', function() {
                book.title = 'what i wish i knew when i was 20';
                expect(book.title).toEqual('What I Wish I Knew When I Was 20');
            });

            it('the first word', function() {
                book.title = 'the man in the iron mask';
                expect(book.title).toEqual('The Man in the Iron Mask');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `this.string` in this line of code:

```
var modifiedString = this.string
```

before you have set `this.string` to have any value.  Perhaps you meant to just use `string`, the argument passed to `titleCreator`.  `this.string` is not the same as `string`.  Since `this.string` has never been assigned, it is `undefined` and therefore any attempt to access a method on it will fail.

It's a little hard to know exactly what your intent was, but perhaps you meant to use use `string` instead of `this.string`:

```
titleCreator(string) {
    // Note that this isn't meant to be a fully fledged title creator, just designed to pass these specific tests
    var littleWords = ["and", "over", "the"]; // These are the words that we don't want to capitalize

    var modifiedString = string
      .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
      .map(function(word,index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
        } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
            return capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
        } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
            return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
        }
    })
    .join(' '); // Joins every element of an array into a string with a space inbetween each value. Basically you created a sentence from an array of words

    return modifiedString;
}
```

From your error description, it also sounds like you may have an issue with how you call `bookTitle` (it should be called as a constructor as in

```
let bk = new (yourModule.bookTitle)("some string")
```

If you want help with that, please show the calling code that calls that constructor so we can advise on that too.

---

Here's a working piece of code that I had to fix several other things in:

```js
    class bookTitle {
        constructor(title) {
            this.title = this.titleCreator(title); // this sets a title value to the bookTitle object/class
        }
    
        titleCreator(string) {
            // Note that this isn't meant to be a fully fledged title creator, just designed to pass these specific tests
            var littleWords = ["and", "over", "the"]; // These are the words that we don't want to capitalize
            
            var self = this;
    
            var modifiedString = string
            .split(' ') // Splits string into array of words, basically breaks up the sentence
            .map(function(word,index) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    return self.capitalize(word); // capitalize the first word of the string
                } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) == -1) {
                    return self.capitalize(word); // capitalize any words that are not little, the -1 is returned by indexOf if it can't find the word in the array
                } else if (littleWords.indexOf(word) >= 0) {
                    return word; // do not capitalize as this word is in the list of littleWords
                }
            })
            .join(' '); // Joins every element of an array into a string with a space inbetween each value. Basically you created a sentence from an array of words
    
            return modifiedString;
    
        }
    
        capitalize(word) {
            return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
            // This function just capitalizes the word given to it
        }
    }
    
    let bookTitles = {
        bookTitle: bookTitle
    };
    
    let book = new bookTitles.bookTitle("some title of the book");
    console.log(book)
```

Things I had to fix:

1. Change `this.string.split(...)` to `string.split(...)`.
2. Define `self` to be `this`.
3. Use `self.capitalize()` instead of `capitalize()` to call method properly (in two places)
4. Pass in a string when calling the constructor (your code was calling the constructor with no parameters which makes an error in your constructor).  Your code requires a string be passed to the constructor.

In addition, it appears that your code thinks that just assigning to the `.title` property will somehow run the `titleCreator()` method and make the proper capitalization.  It will not.  Assigning to the `.title` property just sets that property.  It doesn't run any of your methods.  You could define a setter method to make it run code when you assign to the property, but it would probably make more sense to just create a `setTitle()` method that does what you want (calls `.titleCreator()` and assigns the result to `.title`).

Comment: I tried it that way previously and I got the same error codes. I will edit my original post to include the test cases, I apologize for the lack of context. The idea is just to pass all the Jasmine test cases I wrote

Comment: @mcrav95 - There were several other problems.  Please see what I added to my answer which is in a runnable snippet so you can see the output it creates and lists the changes I had to make.

Comment: Wow thank you for that, really went above and beyond to help me out here. I will review the answer to see what other mistakes were made, thanks again!